# using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that takes a Student's marks in the following format from a .dat file

```
COS1511 30 66 70 49
COS1512 25 76 75 67
COS1521 10 58 90 62
COS1501 50 62 50 57
INF1501 40 82 60 78
INF1511 20 24 80 55
```

The fields are:

Subject ID, Weight of assignment 1 in %, Assignment 1 in %, Weight of assignment 2 in %, Assignment 2 in %,

The output should be the final mark, written to .dat like this:

```
COS1511 54.10%
COS1512 69.25%
COS1521 61.60%
COS1501 59.50%
INF1501 79.60%
INF1511 48.80%
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool isNumber(string str)
{
    for (char c : str) {
        if (isdigit(c) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream inStream;
    ofstream outStream;
    string str;
    vector<int> Marks;
    vector<string> Subjects;
    vector<double> calcdMarks;
    int i = 0;


    inStream.open("Input.dat");
    outStream.open("Output.dat");
    
    while (inStream >> str) {
        if (isNumber(str)) {
            Marks.push_back(stoi(str));
        }
        else
            Subjects.push_back(str);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= Subjects.size()-1; i++) {
        calcdMarks.push_back(Marks[i] * (Marks[i + 1] / 100));
        calcdMarks.push_back(Marks[i + 2] * (Marks[i + 3] / 100));
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= Subjects.size()-1; i++) {
        cout << Subjects[i] << " " << calcdMarks[i] << " " << calcdMarks[i + 1] << endl;
    }

    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that my program output's the following:

```
COS1511 0% 0%
COS1512 0% 0%
COS1521 0% 0%
COS1501 0% 0%
INF1501 0% 0%
INF1511 0% 0%
```

I can't seem to find the reason why. I suspect the problem is here:

```
 for (i = 0; i <= Subjects.size()-1; i++) {
        calcdMarks.push_back(Marks[i] * (Marks[i + 1] / 100));
        calcdMarks.push_back(Marks[i + 2] * (Marks[i + 3] / 100));
    }
```

I'm getting the following warning aswell with `Marks[i] * (Marks[i + 1] / 100` and
`Marks[i + 2] * (Marks[i + 3] / 100)`

"using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value"

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division) help you get started on why the `0`s are popping up?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables as they change, and produce the observe output, what did you see?

Comment: `Marks[i] * (Marks[i + 1] / 100)` is the same as `0`, since `Marks[x]` is between 0 and 100.

Comment: Got it. I needed to cast my integers to doubles.

Comment: FYI -- Your program does no checking to see if those vectors actually have values, and check that `Marks` has all of those entries.  If the input file cannot be opened, that `for` loop will go into hyperspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stoi convert String to Integer.
try to convert result to double.

```
Return Value:
On success, the function returns the converted integral number as an int value.
```